# How can I disable scrolling when "touching" embedded iframe?

Tags: ios, html, iframe, scroll

I'm making a mobile HTML5 app. I've disabled scrolling (and enabled it on certain parts) and it's all good and well, but the problem starts when I embed a Youtube video through an iFrame. It seems that when a user presses an iframe, the whole page scrolls and I can't seem to find a way around this. Adding event listeners does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really can't control what happens in the iframe.

But if you want to be a little clever you can put elements directly over the iframe, like a div or transparent canvas or whatever you want, that will catch all of the events so that the user simply cannot press the iframe.

Not the most ideal, it means users cant press the buttons on the youtube video, but its probably your only real option.